# configuring deployment of web service

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services

I have defined certain rules in a xml file.

When I am running the service it is successfully getting the nodes of the xml file, but when i am deploying the web service, the folder containing the xml file is not copied to the server!!
i.e when i publish it the folder is not there, so the service is throwing error stating that the xml file is not found

What changes should i make to ensure that the xml file is getting copied along with its parent folder during the deployment?

Answer (score 0):

What IDE you are using ?? if is visual studio you can before publish set the property 'Copy to Out Directory' to 'always copy' and set the property 'Build Action' to 'Content' in the xml file propeties. it will copied when you publish the service.